# Sunspot fulltext search - showing search parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I would like to show the search parameter of a search object. I using rails and sunspot.

Lets say I have this book application where store a bunch of books and whould like to search the book by them name and title.

**The book model:**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :author_name

  searchable do
    text :title, :author_name
  end
end
```

**controller:**

```
class BooksController < ApplictionController
  def index
   @search = Book.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
   @results = @search.results
  end
end
```

**view:**

```
<div>
 <h1>You search: </h1>
 <% for result in @results %>
    <li>
      <h3><%= link_to result.title, result %></h3>
      <p><%= result.author_name %></p>
    </li>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

How can I show the search parameter, where is that object?

So it outputs:

```
Your search: Jeff Hawkins
Eggs and butter
Jeff Hawkins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller code to:

```
def index
  @query = params[:search]
  @search = Book.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @results = @search.results
end
```

And then in your view you can just do:

```
<h1>Your search: <%= @query %></h1>
```

Comment: dosent the array it returns when you preform a search have a field with the search-parameter?

Comment: The array won't (`@results`) since it's just an array of active record objects, the `@search` object does, but it's quite deeply embedded - to get the search parameter from there, you'd need to do something like this: `@search.query.fulltext.to_params[:q]` for a simple search. This would not be reliable, and absolutely not resistant to changes to the sunspot gem. You'd be much better off just getting the params as mentioned.